# Installing proprietary AMD drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new laptop, and I would like to install the proprietary drivers so I can use gamma correction.

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4700U 
GPU: Integrated Graphics Renoir

**Output from lspci**

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA -A 1
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c2)    (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Renoir
```

I tried to use the Software & Updates manager, but no proprietary driver shows up. 
I also tried to visit the product's page to see if a linux driver was downloadable, but nothing.

I can provide any other information if needed.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i made it by downloading the tar.xz files from this page:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20

Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 20.20 for Ubuntu 20.04.
Direct link to current: https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz

You must unark the file and run the amdgpu-install or amdgpu-pro-install command. Script usage explained:
https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html

Comment: It works !!
Thank you !

Comment: How do you know its using above drivers? I did installed amdgpu pro drivers but I don't think anything happened? I have Ryzen 4750 pro processor.