# Lenovo thinkbook ubuntu 21.10 suspend/resume failure

Tags: suspend, lenovo

Issue: Whenever laptop suspends (either due to closed lid or due to black screen for certain time), I cannot wake it up. Laptop does not respond to key strokes and power button clicks. As a result I always have to hold power button to shut it down and then power it up again.

```
System:
-Model: Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2 ARE
-Processor: AMD® Ryzen 7 4700u with radeon graphics × 8 
-OS: ubuntu 21.10

Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Device-2: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 driver: loaded: amdgpu 
  note: n/a (using device driver) resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0 5.13.0-22-generic LLVM 12.0.1) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Care to share your GPU driver? Execute `inxi -G` in a terminal and copy  the answer into your **question** by clicking the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1384328/edit) link below your question.

Comment: Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Device-2: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 driver: loaded: amdgpu 
  note: n/a (using device driver) resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0 5.13.0-22-generic LLVM 12.0.1) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2

Comment: My experience with AMD GPU is rather meager, hence only a comment:  Check [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272280/installing-proprietary-amd-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04) on how to install the proprietary AMD drivers. In addition to that there has been a discussion about more recent kernels, that might support the AMD GPU better [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45)

Comment: for Ryzen 5 all the advice I have got has been to accept the default ubuntu drivers and not install propietary. hence I wait for a solution. 3 years now. I did have it, now it is gone. isplay: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: ati,fbdev unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.40.0 5.11.0-43-generic LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] I had the same issue, and here is what I did to solve it.

you have to go to BIOS to change the setting to Linux state.

only problem I am facing so far is no authentication after suspend.

Comment: Hello. I do not think you can call it resolved when you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's a fix in your case, but I had the same issue with my Carbon X1 4gen on Ubuntu 22.04. I was able to work around it by switching to "TPM 1.2" in BIOS settings.

That might not be a viable option for dual-booters.