# Propietary drivers for AMD Renoir GPU on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, amdgpu

I was just wondering if anybody has tried installing AMD proprietary drivers for AMD Renoir on Ubuntu 20.04. The GPU does not appear to be among the [supported ones](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-23-20), however, I can't find information on this specific GPU anywhere and I'm quite puzzled. The open-source ones don't work with OpenCL on this hardware.

I have already read this related [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272280/installing-proprietary-amd-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Comment: I see. Nonetheless, I can't run any OpenCL programs, which is why I'm considering the propietary ones.